# How to vertical center a subfigure?

Tags: vertical-alignment, subcaption

I want to vertical center the first figure with out moving the label position.

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extarticle} %,twoside Usado en latex-ssau-gost-style-master
\usepackage{mutavel}   % Usado en latex-ssau-gost-style-master                  
%\RequirePackage[T2A]{fontenc} 
%\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\RequirePackage[russian]{babel}
    
    %\RequirePackage{subcaption} 
    %\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\asbuk{subfigure}}
      
%%%%%%%%%%TIKZ%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}   
% FIGURES
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 

\newcommand{\tikzAngleOfLine}{\tikz@AngleOfLine}                               
\def\tikz@AngleOfLine(#1)(#2)#3{%                                            
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{%                                                 
        \pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}{%                                             
        \pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}                                               
    \pgfmathsetmacro{#3}{\pgfmathresult}%                                        
}  
\newcommand{\tikzMarkAngle}[3]{                                                
    \tikzAngleOfLine#1#2{\AngleStart}                                              
    \tikzAngleOfLine#1#3{\AngleEnd}                                                
    \draw #1+(\AngleStart:0.15cm) arc (\AngleStart:\AngleEnd:0.15cm);              
}   
% FLOWCHARTS
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,backgrounds,fit}

\tikzset{
    deci/.style={diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt},
    proc/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20,text width=10em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em},
    line/.style={draw, -latex'},
    io/.style={draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm, minimum height=2em},
    data/.style={trapezium, draw, trapezium left angle = 50, trapezium right angle = 130,text width=7em, text centered, minimum height=4em, fill=blue!20,   trapezium stretches body,},
}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    



\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \subfloat[Процесс оптимизации\\ положения лонжеронов]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3cm, auto,thick,scale=0.75, every node/.style={scale=0.6}]
        % Place nodes
        \node (init) [io] {Начало};
        \node (ispea) [data,below of = init] {Исходные данные};
        \node (spea)   [proc, below of=ispea] {Многокритериальная оптимизация};
        \node (res) [proc, below of=spea] {Области проектных переменных и критерев};
        \node (end) [io, below of=res] {Конец};
        \node  [left of=ispea, node distance = 5 cm] {\underline{1ая операция}};
        \node  [left of=spea, node distance = 5 cm] {\underline{2ая операция}};
        \node  [left of=res, node distance = 5 cm] {\underline{3ья операция}};
        % Draw edges
        \path [line] (init) -- (ispea);
        \path [line] (ispea) -- (spea);
        \path [line] (spea) --  (res);
        \path [line] (res) -- node{$\bar{x}_1,\bar{x}_2$} (end);
        \label{fig:scheme_opt}
    \label{fig:scheme_opt}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \subfloat[Процесс\\ нормирования нагрузок]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3cm, auto,thick,scale=0.75, every node/.style={scale=0.6}]
        % Place nodes
        \node (init) [io] {Начало};
        \node (inputdata) [data,below of = init] {Исходные данные};
        \node (calc)   [proc, below of=inputdata] {Расчёт потребного $C_\textup{y сж}^{A',D'}$};
        \node (alpha)   [proc, below of=calc] {Расчёт \\ $C_\textup{y н.сж}^{A',D'}(\alpha = 0^{\circ})$ и $C_\textup{y н.сж}^{A',D'}(\alpha = 10^{\circ})$ };
        \node (comp)   [proc, below of=alpha] {Расчёт $C_\textup{y сж}^{A',D'}$};
        \node (interpol)   [proc, below of=comp] {Интерполация};
        \node (end) [io, below of=interpol] {Конец};
        
        \node  [left of=inputdata, node distance = 5 cm] {\underline{1ая операция}};
        \node  [left of=calc, node distance = 5 cm] {\underline{2ая операция}};
        \node  [left of=alpha, node distance = 5 cm] {\underline{3ья операция}};
        \node  [left of=comp, node distance = 5 cm] {\underline{4ая операция}};
        \node  [left of=interpol, node distance = 5 cm] {\underline{5ая операция}};
        % Draw edges
        \path [line] (init) -- (inputdata);
        \path [line] (inputdata) -- (calc);
        \path [line] (calc) --  (alpha);
        \path [line] (alpha) -- (comp);
        \path [line] (comp) -- (interpol);
        \path [line] (interpol) -- node{ $\alpha(C_\textup{y сж}^{A',D'})$}(end);
        \label{fig:scheme_norm}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \caption{Блоки-схемы субпроцессов}
    \label{fig:det_b}
\end{figure}




\end{document}
```

This code produces the followed figure:

[image]

Comment: The two figures are already vertically aligned: They are bottomaligned. Do you want them to be top aligned or vertically centered?

Comment: Vertically centered.

Comment: Is the file `mutavel.sty` available online?

Comment: You can center most things using `\raisebox{\dimexpr 0.5\depth-0.5\height){...}`.  Technically, you are placing the baseline in the center.

Comment: @Mico, yes. You can download it from https://github.com/protsenkovi/latex-ssau-gost-style . I'm adding come changes to be it full compatible with СТО СГАУ 02068410-004-2018.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not very clear to me, what you mean with "vertical" centered. As figure is now, is looks nice to me.  However, you may like to have the following figure composition:

[image]

This can be simply obtain with use of the `subfigure` environment defined in `subcaption` package:

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extarticle} %,twoside Usado en latex-ssau-gost-style-master
\usepackage{mutavel}   % Usado en latex-ssau-gost-style-master
\usepackage{subcaption}

%%%%%%%%%%TIKZ%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
% FLOWCHARTS
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
                backgrounds,
                chains, 
                fit,
                positioning,
                shapes}

\tikzset{
    deci/.style = {diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=4.5em, 
                   align=flush center, inner sep=0pt},
    proc/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw, fill=blue!20, 
                   text width=10em, minimum height=4em, align=center},
      io/.style = {ellipse, draw, fill=red!20, minimum height=2em},
    data/.style = {trapezium, trapezium stretches body, draw, fill=blue!20, 
                   trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
                   text width=10em, minimum height=4em, align=center},
    line/.style = {draw, -latex'},
  }

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 7mm and 3mm, 
  start chain = going below, 
                thick,
        nodes = {scale=0.6} 
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[every node/.append style={on chain,join=by line}]% Place nodes
\node (init)    [io]    {Начало};
\node (ispea)   [data]  {Исходные данные};
\node (spea)    [proc]  {Многокритериальная оптимизация};
\node (res)     [proc]  {Области проектных переменных и критерев};
\node (end)     [io]    {Конец};
    \end{scope}
\node  [left=of ispea]  {\underline{1ая операция}};
\node  [left=of spea]   {\underline{2ая операция}};
\node  [left=of res]    {\underline{3ья операция}};
%
\path  (res) -- node[right] {$\bar{x}_1,\bar{x}_2$} (end);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Процесс оптимизации положения лонжеронов}
\label{fig:scheme_opt}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill%
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 7mm and 3mm,
  start chain = going below,
                thick,
        nodes = {scale=0.6}
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[every node/.append style={on chain,join=by line}]% Place nodes
\node (init)        [io]    {Начало};
\node (inputdata)   [data]  {Исходные данные};
\node (calc)        [proc]  {Расчёт потребного $C_\textup{y сж}^{A',D'}$};
\node (alpha)       [proc]  {Расчёт \\ $C_\textup{y н.сж}^{A',D'}(\alpha = 0^{\circ})$ и $C_\textup{y н.сж}^{A',D'}(\alpha = 10^{\circ})$ };
\node (comp)        [proc]  {Расчёт $C_\textup{y сж}^{A',D'}$};
\node (interpol)    [proc]  {Интерполация};
\node (end)         [io]    {Конец};
    \end{scope}
\node  [left=of inputdata]  {\underline{1ая операция}};
\node  [left=of calc]       {\underline{2ая операция}};
\node  [left=of alpha]      {\underline{3ья операция}};
\node  [left=of comp]       {\underline{4ая операция}};
\node  [left=of interpol]   {\underline{5ая операция}};
%        
\path [line] (interpol) -- node[right] {$\alpha(C_\textup{y сж}^{A',D'})$} (end);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Процесс нормирования нагрузок}
\label{fig:scheme_norm}
\end{subfigure}%
    \caption{Блоки-схемы субпроцессов}
\label{fig:det_b}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Or you like to have vertical centered only image and aligned `subcaptions`?

[image]

In  this case, the use of a `tabularx` table is convenient:

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extarticle} %,twoside Usado en latex-ssau-gost-style-master
\usepackage{mutavel}   % Usado en latex-ssau-gost-style-master
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularx}

%%%%%%%%%%TIKZ%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
% FLOWCHARTS
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
                backgrounds,
                chains, 
                fit,
                positioning,
                shapes}

\tikzset{
    deci/.style = {diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=4.5em, 
                   align=flush center, inner sep=0pt},
    proc/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw, fill=blue!20, 
                   text width=10em, minimum height=4em, align=center},
      io/.style = {ellipse, draw, fill=red!20, minimum height=2em},
    data/.style = {trapezium, trapezium stretches body, draw, fill=blue!20, 
                   trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
                   text width=10em, minimum height=4em, align=center},
    line/.style = {draw, -latex'},
  }

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 7mm and 3mm, 
  start chain = going below, 
                thick,
        nodes = {scale=0.6} 
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[every node/.append style={on chain,join=by line}]% Place nodes
\node (init)    [io]    {Начало};
\node (ispea)   [data]  {Исходные данные};
\node (spea)    [proc]  {Многокритериальная оптимизация};
\node (res)     [proc]  {Области проектных переменных и критерев};
\node (end)     [io]    {Конец};
    \end{scope}
\node  [left=of ispea]  {\underline{1ая операция}};
\node  [left=of spea]   {\underline{2ая операция}};
\node  [left=of res]    {\underline{3ья операция}};
%
\path  (res) -- node[right] {$\bar{x}_1,\bar{x}_2$} (end);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    &
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 7mm and 3mm,
  start chain = going below,
                thick,
        nodes = {scale=0.6}
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[every node/.append style={on chain,join=by line}]% Place nodes
\node (init)        [io]    {Начало};
\node (inputdata)   [data]  {Исходные данные};
\node (calc)        [proc]  {Расчёт потребного $C_\textup{y сж}^{A',D'}$};
\node (alpha)       [proc]  {Расчёт \\ $C_\textup{y н.сж}^{A',D'}(\alpha = 0^{\circ})$ и $C_\textup{y н.сж}^{A',D'}(\alpha = 10^{\circ})$ };
\node (comp)        [proc]  {Расчёт $C_\textup{y сж}^{A',D'}$};
\node (interpol)    [proc]  {Интерполация};
\node (end)         [io]    {Конец};
    \end{scope}
\node  [left=of inputdata]  {\underline{1ая операция}};
\node  [left=of calc]       {\underline{2ая операция}};
\node  [left=of alpha]      {\underline{3ья операция}};
\node  [left=of comp]       {\underline{4ая операция}};
\node  [left=of interpol]   {\underline{5ая операция}};
%
\path [line] (interpol) -- node[right] {$\alpha(C_\textup{y сж}^{A',D'})$} (end);
    \end{tikzpicture}   \\
%    
\begin{subfigure}[t]{\linewidth}
    \caption{Процесс оптимизации положения лонжеронов}
    \label{fig:scheme_opt}
\end{subfigure} &   \begin{subfigure}[t]{\linewidth}
    \caption{Процесс нормирования нагрузок}
    \label{fig:scheme_norm}
\end{subfigure}%
\end{tabularx}
    \caption{Блоки-схемы субпроцессов}
\label{fig:det_b}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```